# The comments I am retrieving when using the Instagram API are returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

I'm retrieving data from

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/HASHTAG/media/recent?client_id=CLIENT_ID

where
HASHTAG = the hashtag I'm searching
CLIENT_ID = my client id
I am having no trouble retrieving the picture urls and captions but when I try to get the comments the comments are being returned as 'undefined'.
The data is stored in an array called pictures so if I want to get the standard resolution url I just do:

```
for(i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++){
  pictureURL[i] = pictures[i].images.standard_resolution.url;
}
```

Right now the code I'm trying to use to retrieve the comments is :

```
//where 'i' is the index of the pic I'm currently focusing on
for (comment in pictures[i].comments.data) {
            alert(comment.text);
            //using alert just to see what is being retrieved
        }
```

But the issue is that the alerts are only displaying 'undefined' and also they are only displaying undefined when there is a comment (I checked on my phone, if the pic has no comment, there is no alert. If the picture has comments there is 1 alert for each comment.
Can someone please help me out?

Comment: if you do `console.log(comment);` instead of your alert, what do you get in the console? Is there a `text` node as your code tells us? (I don't know the structure of the json they return)

Comment: I don't know he Insragram API, but you're misusing `for..in`. The value of `comment` will always be a property name string, which certainly has no `text` property.

Comment: Thanks! It worked properly when I used a regular for loop instead.

Comment: Just FYI, please don't take offense at me closing your question -- it's simply that T.J. Crowder's excellent answer on that duplicate question already covers anything that I could possibly write in an answer to your question here.

Comment: It's not a duplicate it's a completely different question. This question is specific to the Instagram API and that in this case a for-each loop doesn't work. It isn't about how to do a for-each loop.

Comment: The value in `pictures[i].comments.data` *is* an array (as shown in the "Response" section in [the `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` Instagram API docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent)). I disagree that they're not duplicates: you *are* trying to perform a for-each loop over the elements in an array (which, again, is what `pictures[i].comments.data` is), and you've used the wrong type of looping mechanism for an array, as explained in that answer.

Comment: Neverthless, you've convinced me that this isn't *quite* a duplicate, since your problem arose due to a misunderstanding of the Instagram API response structure, in addition to any misunderstanding of how `for..in` works. I've re-opened and I'm writing an answer.

Comment: Closely related: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `pictures[i].comments.data` is an array, as shown in the "Response" section in the [`/tags/tag-name/media/recent` Instagram API docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#):

```
[{
    "type": "image",
    ...
    "comments": {
        "data": [{
            "created_time": "1296703540",
            "text": "Snow",
            ...
        },
        {
            "created_time": "1296707889",
            "text": "#snow",
            ...
        }],
    ...
```

As you can see, the `data` property in the `comments` object is an array (beginning with `[`).

You're misusing `for..in` on an array. (See [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)) `for..in` loops over *property names* of objects. The value of `comment` will always be a property name string, which certainly has no `text` property.

Instead, you need a plain `for` loop, because `pictures[i].comments.data` is an array:

```
for (var j=0; j<pictures[i].comments.data.length; j++) {
    var comment = pictures[i].comments.data[j];
    alert(comment.text)
}
```

One important note is that even if `pictures[i].comments.data` had been a non-array object, your use of `for..in` still wouldn't be quite right. Your variable `comment` holds property names, and you need to use property-access to get the *value* that a property name refers to:

```
for (commentKey in pictures[i].comments.data) {
    var commentValue = pictures[i].comments.data[commentKey];
    alert(commentValue.text)
}
```

Note that this *might* work for arrays, but:

1. The property names may not loop in numerical order
2. This will loop over *all* iterable properies of the array, not just numeric indices